# Membrane conductance in phase 1 of the cardiac action potential

Tags: cardiology, action-potential

Correct me if I am wrong, but in phase 1 of the cardiac action potential (for ventricle cells) there is flow of potassium ions due to the opening of transdent potassium channels. To me this would correspond to an (sudden) increase in the conductance of the membrane to the potassium ions, $g_K$, however looking at [graphs on the internet](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cardiac%20action%20potential%20conductance&safe=active&biw=1440&bih=842&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKhL-y-r3JAhXBWxoKHeDlCFIQ_AUIBigB#safe=active&tbm=isch&q=cardiac%20action%20potential%20potassium%20conductance)  do not seem to indicate such a change in conductance. Please can someone explain why such a change does not occur (sources would be helpful).